# Sorting Cisco IOS CDP Neighbors output with Python

Tags: python, cisco

I currently have some Python code to take the output from Cisco IOS' `show cdp neighbors` command and generate a CSV which I then paste in Excel, to be ordered by local interface with this: `=SORTBY(I12:N38,LEFT(J12:J38,SEARCH("/",J12:J38)-1),1,MID(SUBSTITUTE(J12:J38,"/","^",2),SEARCH("^",SUBSTITUTE(J12:J38,"/","^",2))+1,2)+0,1)`

To simplify things, I have been trying to emulate this behavior and order the CSV in Python without much luck. I can sort a simple list of interfaces with natsorted() or this modified block of code (credit to Evan from the comments at https://keepalives.wordpress.com/2013/06/05/sorting-cisco-interface-names-in-python/):

```
def cisco_interface_key(x):
    regex = re.compile(r'(?P<interface_type>[a-zA-Z]*)(?P<port>.*)')
    result = regex.search(x)
    if result:
        interface_type = result.group("interface_type")
        port = result.group("port")
        port_split = [int(z) for z in port.split("/")]
        port_split.insert(0,interface_type)
        return tuple(port_split)
    return 0

list1 = ['GigabitEthernet1/0/2', 'GigabitEthernet1/0/3', 'GigabitEthernet2/0/4', 'GigabitEthernet3/0/1', 'GigabitEthernet1/0/11']

list1 = sorted(list1, key=cisco_interface_key)
print(list1)
```

Works great! If your information is only the interfaces, it will error if passed a dict or list object.

I'm trying to sort either a dictionary or a list like this:

```
list2 = ["Device ID,Local Intrfce,Holdtme,Capability,Platform,Port ID",
"MAC1,Gig 1/0/7,144,H P M,IP Phone,Port 1",
"MAC3,Gig 1/0/24,155,H P M,IP Phone,Port 1",
"MAC2,Gig 1/0/12,133,H P M,IP Phone,Port 1",
"MAC8,Gig 1/0/17,143,H P M,IP Phone,Port 1"]
```

```
listcsv = list(csv.reader(list2))
list3 = natsorted(listcsv, key = lambda row: row[1])
```

natsorted() appears to be working, although it will place my headers at the bottom of the file - not ideal. This is the first time I have ever touched 'lambda', and have no real understanding of it.

Is there a way to skip the CSV headers when using natsort, or otherwise pass a dict/list to the RegEx function? Ideally, I would prefer working with RegEx as it doesn't require installing additional libraries.

Thanks!

Comment: skip the 1st item from the list with the following construct `list2 = list2[1:]`

Comment: Outstanding idea! I replaced the natsort with `list3 = natsorted(listcsv[1:], key = lambda row: row[1])` and then just add listcsv[0] as my first writeline when I'm creating the output file. Output seems what I would expect it to be.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to convert your `list2` as Pandas dataframe and `sort_values` by `natsort_key` as key function:

```
import pandas as pd
from natsort import natsort_key
import io

data = io.StringIO('\n'.join(list2))
df = pd.read_csv(data).sort_values('Local Intrfce', key=natsort_key)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  Device ID Local Intrfce  Holdtme Capability  Platform Port ID
0      MAC1     Gig 1/0/7      144      H P M  IP Phone  Port 1
2      MAC2    Gig 1/0/12      133      H P M  IP Phone  Port 1
3      MAC8    Gig 1/0/17      143      H P M  IP Phone  Port 1
1      MAC3    Gig 1/0/24      155      H P M  IP Phone  Port 1
```

Comment: Dataframes and natsort_key seem like a MUCH more elegant solution to my issue than manipulating lists, and this method of sorting helped quite a bit with the other question for sorting ARP output. Thanks!